# The application “SomeApp.app” can’t be opened?

Tags: macos, python-2.7, shell, applescript, runtime-error

I have created an Application from AppleScript. Here is the code,

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    set shell to do script "clear" in window 1
    do script "python ~/Desktop/Prog/Prog.py" in shell
end tell
```

I am getting the error message `The application Prog can’t be opened` when running from the Applications folder. However it works fine in other folders. Even works fine in sub-folder in Applications folder. Only not working in Applications folder.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try: `term> chmod uog+x SomeApp.app/Contents/MacOS/applet`